# Destroy Post issue, renders show action and does not destroy post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I click on the Destroy link the post is opened (renders show action) rather than destroyed.

The line in view:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),
                method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

posts_controller.rb fragment:

```
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path
  end
```

Rake routes:

```
                posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                      POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
             new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
            edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                 post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                      PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                      PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                      DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
```

In routes.rb

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

In development.log when I clicked the destroy link:

```
Started GET "/posts/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-28 21:51:40 +0000
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
  [1m[36mComment Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?[0m  [["post_id", 5]]
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (7.6ms)
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (12.6ms)
  [1m[35mAdmin Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 15.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

I know that the issue might be caused as I use "resources :posts" in my routes.rb however how can I delete the post then?

If you need any other info please let me know. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add this in the /layout/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

What you were doing:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
```

So when you click the link you are giving it `post_path(post)` and this says to the routes okay go to the post_path and pass in **that** post that I've clicked on. Whereas what you should have done is just given it the object `post` and then rails takes care of the rest of it.

Comment: Thanks for helping again David. However, when I use what you suggested I get the same exact reaction. It renders the show action...

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou not a problem. Okay, can you try and replace `redirect_to posts_path` for  `redirect_to posts_url`

Comment: same issue. Well, even when I click it does not destroy the post. I think it does not even use the Destroy method.